# Qwerty to azerty PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide, azerty-keyboard

I have an azerty keyboard and as know I can switch from azerty to qwerty on the computer itself. But I don't know how I manage to do that but my keyboard is now in qwerty mode (but only inside PhpStorm !). I tried to close PhpStorm and launch it again but still with qwerty.

Do you know how I can return to the azerty inside PhpStorm?

Comment: What IDE version & national layout are you using? Try to go to Help -> Edit Custom Properties, add the next property into the file: com.jetbrains.use.old.keyevent.processing=true

Comment: JetBrains PhpStorm 2017.1.3 x64  and the layout is in english.

Comment: Please check how this works in latest EAP build: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program

Comment: Well...I don't really know why but a full reboot of the computer have solved the issue.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: cool, you're welcome